# Standard error in a group of samples

Tags: standard-error

I just want to check my understanding around a standard error in a group of samples.

Let's imagine I am measuring the water use a household at a certain hour of the day. Some data:

- The population is 600K properties
- I have 100 "areas", with each area consisting of ~50 properties each
- So in total there are 5000 properties in the sample

Now let's imagine that the mean is 7 litres/prop/ day and the standard deviation is 2 l/prop/day.

Is it correct to say the following:

- The standard error per area = 2 / sqrt(50) = 0.282
- The standard error across the 100 areas = 0.282 / sqrt(100) = 0.028

This is the same if we had taken you just do the standard error of the 5000 property sample 2 / sqrt (5000)

I was half expecting the grouping of samples in "areas" would have introduced additional uncertainty, but it doesn't appear to.

Is the above correct?

Comment: It is more common to talk about the "standard error of the mean"  as a measure of the dispersion of the sample mean as an estimate of the population mean.  But I do not see random samples here.  Are you assuming that water use is distributed the same way in each property regardless of area?

Comment: Yes - I am assuming that water use is randomly distributed across the entire population. So I guess in effect you are taking a sample of a sample ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the *standard error of the mean*

If each property has water usage independently and identically distributed with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ then

- the mean water usage of a sample of $50$ such properties would be distributed with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{50}}$
- the average of $100$ means from such samples of $50$ such properties would be distributed with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\dfrac{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{50}}}{\sqrt{100}}$
- this is the same distribution of the mean water usage as from a sample of $5000$ such properties, as their mean would be distributed with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{5000}}$

So in that case it makes no difference whether you make the intermediate calculations or not.  I would have thought this was intuitively appealing, as the overall mean should not depend on how you slice up the calculation.

It could make a difference if your original samples were not all the same size (instead you could take a weighted average of the original means, with the weights proportional to the number of properties in each group).  It could make a difference if the different groups had different expected water usage (a group of $50$ student residences might tend to use less water than a group of $50$ farms).